# CakePHP: Find if is mobile browser in a helper (no access to request handler)

Tags: cakephp, mobile, request, handler

I need to know in a helper in a CakePHP application if the device is mobile, I would love to use $this->RequestHandler->isMobile(), but the request handler component is not available in helpers. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import the class and use it anywhere in the framework like so:

```
App::import('Component', 'RequestHandler'); // import class
$requestHandler = new RequestHandlerComponent(); // instantiate class
$isMobile = $requestHandler->isMobile(); // call method
var_dump($isMobile); // output: bool(true) or bool(false)
```

(Tested from helper and gives correct results for Firefox and iPhone)

Comment: I got error `getController() on a non-object` Not working. :(

Answer (score 1):

Also, any options you set in the `Controller::helpers` property will be passed to the helper:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(/*...*/, 'RequestHandler');

    public $helpers = array(/*...*/, 'MyHelper');

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->helpers['MyHelper']['mobile'] = $this->RequestHandler->isMobile();
    }

}
```

You can catch the options array in your helper's constructor:

```
class MyHelper extends AppHelper {

    protected $_defaultOptions = array('mobile' => false);

    public function __construct($options) {
        $this->options = array_merge($this->_defaultOptions, $options);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer suggests using a component inside a helper which should be avoided as components are for use solely in controllers and will result in errors as mentioned by Anupal.

The simple solution is to use the `CakeRequest` class that `RequestHandlerComponent` uses. So in your helper you can do:-

```
App::uses('CakeRequest', 'Utility');
$isMobile = (new CakeRequest())->is('mobile');
```